# Js code for the stop of a video slider

Tags: javascript

I have created a video slider, that is, I have two videos that switch between one and the other when I click on a circle that I have taken from fontawesome.com. When I clic on the bottom PLAY to start the video, it does not stop when I switch to the next video of the slider. I would like when I change the video, the previous one is stopped.

I show below the js code that I have written so far. If you can help me to know what I should include in this code for the stop of the video that I switch it.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var videoItems = $('.slidervideo li').length;


// Pagination --
for(i= 1; i <= videoItems; i++){ 
$('.pagination-slider').append('<li><span class="fa fa-circle"></span> 
</li>');
}

//------------------------

$('.slidervideo li').hide(); // Ocultanos todos los slides
$('.slidervideo li:first').show(); // Mostramos el primer slide
$('.pagination-slider li:first').css({'color': '#CD6E2E'});

//Ejecutamos todas las funciones
$('.pagination-slider li').click(paginationslider);


// FUNCIONES =========================================================

function paginationslider(){
var paginationsliderPos = $(this).index() + 1;

$('.slidervideo li').hide();
$('.slidervideo li:nth-child('+ paginationsliderPos +')').fadeIn(); 


$('.pagination-slider li').css({'color': '#858585'});
$(this).css({'color': '#CD6E2E'});  
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there...

Let's see what the `hide()` function does:

> element.hide(): calling the hide() function on the element (jquery element) hides the elmenet by adding the `display: none` property to it.

There is no way this CSS property going to pause/play the video.

So, you have to add the code for pausing the video as well.

```
$('.slidervideo li:nth-child('+ paginationsliderPos +') video').pause()
```

* I am assuming you have a video element inside of the `.slidervideo li` element.

And you don't need a jQuery element to execute the `.pause()` method as it is an HTMLMediaElement method.

Edit: To pause a youtube video loaded in the iframe, is a different approach.

Have a look at their API's
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

First, you need to update the iframe url with parameter `enablejsapi`

```
<iframe id="existing-iframe-example"
        width="640" height="360"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1"
        frameborder="0"
        style="border: solid 4px #37474F"
></iframe>
```

and then you can call the `stopVideo` method exposed.

```
player.stopVideo()
```

In your case, it will be invoked as:

```
$('.slidervideo li:nth-child('+ paginationsliderPos +') video').get(0).stopVideo();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I tried with this line code and the video is not stopped when I clic on the bullet  (circle -pagination) got from fontawesome.com. 
Effectively, the video element is inside of .slidervideo li. It is a video embedded from youtube using the tag <iframe>.
Any addittional help?
Sorry, but I am in my first steps learning this code.

Comment: Any additional ideas? Thanks

Comment: @fernanf, Play/pause an iframe youtube video is a different thing altogether. You have to use the API's exposed by the youtube and use them. Have a look at their API's https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference. I'll update the answer as well.

Comment: I know how a video have to be stopped/paused according to API documentation. The question is that the video have to be paused when I click on the bullet to switch to next video into my slider. I tried with code line shown above, $('.slidervideo li:nth-child('+ paginationsliderPos +') video').pause(), but it does not work. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Did you try the updated code?
You just have to select the element and invoke the API method.